# PHP: write in php://input

Tags: php, yii, wrapper, superglobals

I would like to know how I could write something in "php://input".

Actually I would like to know if I can use this stream like a superglobal.

**Example with $_POST**

```
file1: $_POST['param'] = "test";

file2: $param = $_POST['param'];
```

**What I want**

```
file1: ?????????????

file2: $param = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Do I need to throw a POST request to from file1 to file2?

Thanks for read me :)

Have a nice day

Michaël S.

Comment: $_POST variables are set when using POST as HTTP request method

Comment: *php://stdin is read-only, whereas php://stdout and php://stderr are write-only.* http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 2):

> php://input is a **read-only** stream that allows you to read raw data
> from the request body.
> ([PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php))

Maybe, you will find [unix-sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), or [shared memory](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) useful?